# Pyautogui bug on mac? triple clicking for no reason when clicking function is used

Tags: python, pyautogui

When I run the `pyautogui.click()` alone together with time command. I see that the `pyautogui.click()` command clicks three times everytime the code is being runned... This has been bugging me for 3 days and I have to hand over an assigment today that requires use of this today.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
import time
import pyautogui


time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click()
```

I figured out that it clicked three times by using a virtual keyboard on google that showed how many characters that was produced by the command.

Comment: I have the same problem so there might be something wrong with pyautogui for Mac.